# How to refetch the access token in a Python script automatically after it expires?

Tags: python, api, discord, bots, ed

so I am working on fetching data from an api using access token only. I have created two python scripts, one for fetching the token and the other for fetching data. I have created a common variable 'token' for both scripts. However when token expires in 15 minutes, I have to restart the script manually. Is there an solution for this problem?

Auth Code:

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

**token** = response.json()['access_token']

Fetch Sample:

```
  response2 = requests.request("GET", qurl, headers=headers2, data=payload2)
  r2=response2.json()
  payload={}
  headers = {
  'Host': 'proxy.sample.com',
  'Accept': 'application/vnd.sample.v1+json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic 
  MFQxOE5HYmFsUURGYzBnWkh6b3ZwZVJkN0a1Y3BMQ3w6dnwnamFZa3Ric2p4OUFPUg==',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'br;q=1.0, gzip;q=0.9, deflate;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=1.0, ar-US;q=0.9',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'User-Agent': 'SampleApp/3.37.0 (com.sample.mobile.consumer; build:3.#; iOS 
   14.4.1) Alamofire/5.2.2',
   'access_token': token
```

Note: I don't want more than one instance of the script at once.

Comment: you could create a cron job that runs the script automatically every 15 mins

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your code!

Comment: Added sample of my code!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, assuming you're using a loop you could use **except**.
Therefore when the error procs the code will log you back in and continue

e.g.

```
while True:
    try:
        {script here}

    except {ErrorType}:
        print('token expired')
        {relogin code}
        continue
```

Comment: perhaps i was misunderstanding, i thought you needed to reauthenticate. 
If you only need to restart the code after the error, ignore {relogin code} and it should work!

Comment: I tried your way, keep getting syntax error for some reason.. I put the while True at the beginning of the script and the except at the end.